# What for [a..] function in VBA excel?

Tags: vba, excel

[image: xxx]

I would like to ask the functionality of "[a ..]" in visual basic.
I write code like this.

```
ListBox1.ColumnWidths = "50;60;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;70;0;0;70;0;0;90;0;0;70;0;0;60;0;0;60"            'ukuran kolom
ListBox1.columnCount = 32
ListBox1.List = ws.Range("a4:af" & [a30].End(3).Row).Value
```

but compile error. box appears "can find project or library".
anyone can help me?

UPDATE full :

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim nom As Integer
Dim say As Long, a As Byte

Private Sub userform_initialize()
Sheets("VIP").Select
Set ws = Sheets("VIP")
ListBox1.ColumnWidths = "50;60;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;70;0;0;70;0;0;90;0;0;70;0;0;60;0;0;60"            'ukuran kolom
ListBox1.columnCount = 32
ListBox1.List = ws.Range("a4:af" & [a30].End(3).Row).Value

Private Sub ListBox1_Click()
Set ws = Sheets("VIP")
Label8 = ListBox1.ListIndex + 1
yay = Label8.Caption
End Sub
```

Comment: I can't tell you what it's supposed to be doing,  A better question is, **what are *you* trying to accomplish?**

Comment: @ashleedawg Are you sure that `[A30]` this is incorrect syntax?

Comment: @JohnyL - Nope. Comment removed; See below.

Comment: I want to specify the final boundary of the cell in the listbox

Comment: `final boundary of the cell in the listbox`?  Hmm. The boundary of the _Input Range_ for the listbox?

Comment: @YanLimaBenua I answered your question (in title), but you ask completely another question.

Comment: @johnyL sorry ... i am not out of the title, i just want to know why sintax is not working

Comment: @YanLimaBenua Not out of the title? You're asking about what `[]` for - I answered you.

Comment: maybe for the explanation sintax [] used for the listbox I need for example.

Comment: @YanLimaBenua Change `[A30]` to `Range("30")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is `Range` object, same as `Evaluate`:

```
Sub FF()
    MsgBox TypeName([A1])           'Shows "Range"
    MsgBox TypeName(Evaluate("A1")) 'Shows "Range"
End Sub
```

**UPDATE**

The same way an array can be created:

```
Dim x
For Each x in [{1, 2, 3}]
   MsgBox x
Next
```

Comment: Hmm, 25 years with Excel and I had no idea that `[A1]` was an alternate way to represent a range.  Are you kidding me? All this time I could have used, for example, `debug.print [A1]` instead of `debug.print Range("A1")`?!  11 keystrokes saved, times a _billion_...  *sigh* :-)

Comment: What else aren't you telling me?!  ...I assume it's not considered correct syntax though? (otherwise I would have seen it, like, _ever_?)

Comment: I updated answer - there's one more thing for you :)

Comment: yes, that's what makes me ask myself. this code I previously made from windows8 operating system. but after I open and write code on windows10 operating system, all the problem, code compile error

Comment: Come on, do not joke around. help me solve this problem

Comment: Well _here's_ a link I should have had a long time ago: [All About Shortcut Range Notation](http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/content.php?148-Shortcut-Range-Notation)  .@JohnyL -   Did ***you*** know that using the [shorthand] _increases_ file size?

Comment: Not joking; learning.  Give me an example of what the Input Range should be.  What is in cell A4?  And nearby it?

Comment: Operating System won't affect VBA syntax.  But to be clear: are we talking VBA, Visual Basic, VB.Net? You've mentioned all of them.

Comment: @ashleedawg This syntax exists only in VBA.

Comment: @JohnyL - Sry, not _you_...  Question title = VBA, 1st Line of Q = Visual basic, Tags = [tag:vb.net], [tag:vba].   I figured it was VBA but wanted to **clarify** since there seems to be a disconnect; I don't understand the OP's question.  I'm out, I give up on this one;\ all yours...  :-)

Comment: @ashleedawg You asked under *my* answer while you should do it under OP's question :)

Comment: @YanLimaBenua So, I have answered your question in the title. If you want answer for another question, you should ask new question.

Comment: @JohnyL Sorry, too much screentime on SO today,  _really_ trying for my 2K rep, and then I was totally thrown off by the [range] thing. You're only 500 rep? You seem to know your stuff, have you seen [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-vba+or+vba+or+ms-access+or+excel+or+excel-formula?sort=featured&pageSize=50)?  Easy rep.  :-)

Comment: Thank you for all. well, now is the time to practice. i will continue my activities.

Comment: @ashleedawg Even though that syntax exists (and I have known about it for years) I never use it. It is only good for range literals whereas `Range()` plays nice with variables. Furthermore `Range()` hooks onto Intellisense but `[ ]` doesn't. Also, for a code readability point of view, if you are going to be using `Range()` for other purposes, it is more consistent to use it uniformly rather than `Range()` sometimes and `[ ]` on others. It is a matter of taste perhaps, but the fact that it shows up so infrequently in Stack Overflow answers suggests that my taste here is not idiosyncratic.

Comment: @john-coleman -- I assumed there was a reason I haven['t seen it in use.  But speaking of intellisense, I've been trying to figure out why it works _sometimes_. For example, popping up **Properties/Methods** in VBE when I type the dot after a Range, or within a `With/End With`, but **not other times**, regardless of compile state, code in break, etc. Any quick thoughts or point to an explanation?  _(Oops, I'm hijacking OPs thread!)_

Comment: @ashleedawg I've noticed similar things at times (especially when dealing with code involving charts, for some reason). I haven't really paid enough attention to the problem to know just when and why it pops up.